# GoLand Remote Debugger unable to set breakpoints

Tags: docker, go, goland, dlv

I'm trying to debug something in a go microservce, but when I go set a breakpoint, it comes up with the breakpoint unavailable and get the following error

`cannot find debugger path for <PATH TO FILE>`

I have checked the go modules in the settings. Doesn't matter where the breakpoint is. I've done invalidate caches and restart. This *used* to work.

My Docker file to build the debug service:

```
FROM golang:1.21-alpine

WORKDIR /user-service

# Install dependencies in go.mod and go.sum
COPY user_service/go.mod user_service/go.sum ./
COPY ./proto ../proto
COPY ./common ../common
RUN go mod download

# Build Delve
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

# Copy rest of the application source code
COPY ./user_service ./

# Compile the application to /app.
# Skaffold passes in debug-oriented compiler flags
ARG SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS
ARG PORT=8081
RUN echo "Go gcflags: ${SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS}"
RUN go build -gcflags="${SKAFFOLD_GO_GCFLAGS}" -mod=readonly -v -o app

# Run the app
EXPOSE ${PORT} 40002
CMD ["dlv", "--listen=:40002", "--headless=true", "--api-version=2", "--accept-multiclient", "exec", "app"]
```

[image: Go Modules Enabled]

EDIT:

Here's my project structure

```
└── Project Root/
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── go.work/
    │   └── ....
    ├── common/
    │   └── pkg/
    │       └── ...
    ├── proto/
    │   └── ....
    └── <Microservice>/
        ├── docker/
        │   ├── cloud/
        │   │   └── Dockerfile
        │   ├── debug/
        │   │   └── Dockerfile
        │   └── local/
        │       └── Dockerfile
        └── internal/
            └── main.go
            └── (go code)
```

> Try opening `user_service`

This doesn't work. This messes up the relative paths I have in the project. For more context, it's a mono-repo for microservice application. We're a really small team so distributed repos don't make sense, so I have everything in one.

I'll explain the difference in the docker files.

`cloud` is meant to build image for the cloud

`local` is meant to be an image for local development

`debug` is meant to be local, with the debugger attached.

> ensure relative paths are available

They are. I can run the local docker-compose file just fine, and the only difference between the two docker files is the presence of `dlv`

> Path mappings

I'm not sure where I should be looking here, nor what the paths should be. I'm relatively new to go (coming from Java) so I'm not 100% familiar with what the paths should be. I did try several variations of docker volumes but still nothing.

```
- ${PROJECT_ROOT}/user_service:[./ | / | ${PROJECT_ROOT}]/user_service
```

What's odd to me is this used to work like a month ago. I haven't touched those dockerfiles, so I'm not sure what's up there.

It's also worth noting that the paths reported by goland are correct and there. So I don't know why it's saying it cant' find a file that's clearly there? Meaning it can't find it in the docker container? But then adding the volume doesn't solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is similar to [issue GO-15059](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-15059/breakpoint-not-available-cannot-find-path-for), which has the same kind of issue without docker, but using a remote development environment.

> It looks like its trying to find source code and searching the same path as the source system, a truncated suffix path on the remote system, and a root-based path on the remote system.
>
> Will it work if you open arista project as a root project in the IDE instead of `~/go/src` (File | Open) and make sure that the remote machine has the same file structure (`arista/vendor/<...>`) as you did for a quick test?

In your case, the error message `cannot find debugger path for <PATH TO FILE>` should be the result of a difference between the path that [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) is using to reference your files and the actual file system path within the Docker container.

When debugging a Go application in a container via GoLand, the IDE needs to map the local source code to the corresponding code inside the container.

So make sure the Path Mappings in your GoLand run/debug configuration are set up correctly. These mappings tell GoLand how to correlate files in your project with files in the Docker container.
In GoLand, go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`, then select your debug configuration. Under `Docker container settings`, ensure that `Path Mappings` are correct.

Your Docker configuration should mount your project directory to the correct path in the container, matching the working directory (`/user-service`) as mentioned in your Dockerfile.
If you are using docker-compose, make sure the volumes section is correctly configured to mount your local directory to `/user-service` in the container.

Your Dockerfile shows the installation of Delve and its configuration. Make sure the `--listen` and `--headless` flags are correctly set, and that the `dlv` command is correctly pointing to your compiled application.

Double-check also that your source code and its dependencies are correctly placed and referenced. Your Dockerfile shows copying of certain directories like `./proto` and `./common` to `../proto` and `../common` respectively, which are outside the working directory `/user-service`. If these paths are incorrect or not accessible, it might cause issues.

Comment: As usual, checking the IDE logs via `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` is never a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks you kindly! I've updated my post with responses.